# Do physical copies of Torna - The Golden Country also come with a digital copy?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2, xenoblade-2-torna-golden-country

The [store description](https://videogamesplus.ca/products/xenoblade-chronicles-2-torna-the-golden-country-switch) for physical copies of *Xenoblade Chronicles 2 - Torna The Golden Country* says it comes with a download code for the *Xenoblade Chronicles 2 Expansion Pass*. Confusingly, the digital version of the [XB2 Expansion Pass](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/xenoblade-chronicles-2-expansion-pass-70070000000644-switch/) also comes with a copy of *Torna - The Golden Country*.

Does the Expansion Pass download code included with physical copies of *Torna - The Golden Country* also include a digital copy of *Torna - The Golden Country*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confusing, but through personal experience by having purchased the physical edition of Torna - The Golden Country, I can confirm that it does *not* provide a digital version to Torna - The Golden Country.

The digital code it comes with for the Xenoblade Chronicles 2 Expansion Pass is slightly different than the on the eStore, redeeming *only* the expansion pass and not Torna - The Golden Country.

This confusion is cleared up through [Nintendo Support](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/41819/%7E/is-there-a-difference-between-the-expansion-pass-and-the-torna%3A-golden-country)

> Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Torna The Golden Country includes the same story that is included in the Xenoblade Chronicles 2 Expansion Pass, and **a download code for packs 1-4 of the Expansion Pass DLC**
>
> There are two ways to get the full content:
>
> - Xenoblade Chronicles 2 + Expansion Pass (includes DLC Packs 1-4 and the Torna story)
> - Xenoblade Chronicles 2 + Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Torna (includes a download code for DLC Packs 1-4, playable in Xenoblade Chronicles 2 only)
>
> Because the content in the Expansion Pass is the same content included in Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Torna ~ The Golden Country, there is no reason to purchase both items.

Comment: Are you not able to access Torna through the main menu of XB2 after redeeming the code?

Comment: @Stevoisiak That’s a negative. A option in the main menu never appear. I also added a link to Nintendo Support that supports my experience

Comment: Looks like the [Xenoseries wiki](https://www.xenoserieswiki.org/wiki/Xenoblade_Chronicles_2_Expansion_Pass#Torna_.7E_The_Golden_Country) says the same thing: "*Standalone copies of Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Torna ~ The Golden Country come with a redeemable code for the expansion pass. This code includes all content from the expansion pass, except for Xenoblade Chronicles 2: Torna ~ The Golden Country.*"